# I get a java.lang.NullPointerException when the server waits

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, wait, distributed

I'm working on a school project, and the task is to learn to create very *very* basic nodes for a 'distributed network' (it doesn't really deserve to be called that). Right now though, I can't make my "nodes" wait, because when I do, they immediately throw an error. It doesn't crash the server (threads can fail without damaging anything), but I can't pass anything to a "node" if the moment I ask it to wait it crashes.

Right now, this is the part of the server-side code that tells it to wait.

```
while (node == 1)
            {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    try {
                        wait(); // thread dies as client crashes here.
                        System.out.println("I waited.");
                        node = 2;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        System.err.println("This is a thread error.");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("And the Wait Ended.");
                response = Response.newBuilder()
                        .setResponseType(Response.ResponseType.REPLY)
                        .setMessage("You waited.")
                        .build();
            }
```

(Yes, the while loop isn't doing anything right now. I want to get the wait behavior working before doing more code)

This is the part of the server-side code that would end the wait is here (I don't think this part matters, because it throws *before* this code is reached, but this part of the code runs fine.

```
                        response = Response.newBuilder()
                                .setResponseType(Response.ResponseType.REPLY)
                                .setMessage(op.getUnencoded())
                                .build();
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            notifyAll();
                        }
                        quit = true;
                        System.out.println("Echoed");
                        break;
```

And the "node" looks like this.

```
        try {
            // connect to the server
            serverSock = new Socket(host, port);

            // write to the server
            out = serverSock.getOutputStream();
            in = serverSock.getInputStream();

            op.writeDelimitedTo(out);

            // read from the server
            response = Response.parseDelimitedFrom(in);

            // print the server response. 
            System.out.println(response.getMessage());
            // wait on the server
            response = Response.parseDelimitedFrom(in); /// it seems to die here.
            System.out.println(response.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (in != null)   in.close();
            if (out != null)  out.close();
            if (serverSock != null) serverSock.close();
        }
```

What's more annoying was that it didn't throw an exception back when I had the monitor set up wrong. It waited forever, but the thread waited fine. Switch to monitoring a 'lock' rather than having the whole method synchronized (which didn't work because each thread was a new object and new monitor, I think?) made this problem start. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here, and the lecture doesn't talk about wait at all (maybe I was supposed to do busy waiting or something? That sounds terrible).

edit:
This is the full error.
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "buffers.ResponseProtos$Response.getMessage()" because "response" is null`

Edit:
It's unclear why putting a thread into 'wait' is causing the null point error exception, not what a null point exception is.

edit: On the server side, it gets this error instead.

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner
        at java.base/java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
        at server.Server.run(Server.java:72)
```

Comment: It should be either `synchronized (lock) { lock.wait() ...}` or `synchronized (this) { wait(); ...}`, but that will cause a different exception, not a `NullPointerException`. Please clarify. Post the stack trace. Edit it into your question.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "buffers.ResponseProtos$Response.getMessage()" because "response" is null

Comment: You need to put the full stack trace into your question, not just the exception message.

Comment: *"On the server side, it gets this error instead ...."* -  That is a different bug in your code.  Now you should search for Q&As involving >that< error message.   (Hint: you are calling `notifyAll` on the wrong object.  If you are synchronizing on `lock`, you should use that object as the target for `wait` and `notify` / `notifyAll` calls ... while you are holding the mutex for `lock`.  This is explained in the javadocs for `java.lang.Object` ... and tutorials, books, etc.)